# How to restrict ViewPart to resize, when I have added new perspective to Eclipse

Tags: swt, eclipse-rcp, jface

I have added new perspective in eclipse. On that I want to have ui like.

---

Eclipse menubar

---

This is a view and this must be fixed. Want to restrict user to resize this view.

---

I dont find any property on view to restrict user from resizing the View.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you know how to add the perspective & view to the `plugin.xml`.

---

**Perspective**

```
public class MyPerspective implements IPerspectiveFactory
{
    @Override
    public void createInitialLayout(final IPageLayout layout)
    {
         layout.addStandaloneView(MyView.ID, false, IPageLayout.TOP, 0.95f, layout.getEditorArea());

         final IViewLayout viewLayout = layout.getViewLayout(MyView.ID);
         layout.setCloseable(false);
         layout.setMovable(false);
    }
}
```

---

**ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor**

```
public ApplicationWorkbenchWindowAdvisor extends WorkbenchWindowAdvisor
{
    ....

    @Override
    public void preWindowOpen()
    {
         final IWorkbenchWindowConfigurer configurer = getWindowConfigurer();
         configurer.setShowCoolBar(true);
    }

    ....
}
```

Comment: This will be helpful if we have RCP application. however I have perspective in eclipse itself does it work for eclipse aplication?

Comment: @PrasadSDeshpande Cool. Post your answer and accept it. :-)